# hardcoded password / credentials

Tags: python, security, hardcoded

I am in the middle of reviewing security for Python code.

For that, I am using tools like Bandits (a module for Python) and DeepCode (www.deepcode.ai). Bandit found that there are some vulnerabilities in hardcoding login and password, whereas no vulnerabilities was found with DeepCode. here is the code in question :

```
# Guest only login
# Used for Login as Guest button and login the current session as GUEST
APP_GUEST_USERNAME = "ppams.asguest"
APP_GUEST_PASSWORD = "ppams123456"

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '10-6d$q$&xxc9heb(hjeda$w%7pxC#+hhx%b0xl&_q(p8(u#uu'
```

I found articles that credentials should not be hardcoded. Here are some articles : https://qxf2.com/blog/dont-hardcode-usernames-and-passwords-in-your-test-scripts/ ; https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Use_of_hard-coded_password ; https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/1059-create-more-secure-applications-don-t-hard-code-credentials-instead-use-application-hardening/106-risk-management.

So, whats the risk of using hard coded credentials ? Can you show me some samples ?
What is the alternative way to secure credentials if credentials cant be hard coded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to take into account, first of all you will not be able to make your project public via a repository because your codes will be accessible in clear. 
Secondly, if you want to share your code with friends without necessarily going through a public repository, they will have access to your API keys or passwords. 
And thirdly, a common danger that we tend to forget is that if your computer gets corrupted and the person comes across your script/program, they will also have access.
So to summarize, it is not a vulnerability if your script stays on a computer cut off from the Internet because it is safe, but it is still a bad practice. On the other hand, if your code is shared for any reason, it becomes dangerous.

Ps: an alternative is to create an.ini file for example where you will store all your sensitive data but that you will not share publicly.